# List of data frames with exponential function draws based on rows in another data frame

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and trying to do some simulation.
I have a dataframe of cohorts with various settings

```
n = 10000
ir.1 = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.05)
ir.2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
setting.1 = c(0.5, 0.9)
setting.2 = c(0.4, 0.6)

cohorts = expand.grid(n = n, ir.1 = ir.1, ir.2 = ir.2, setting.1 = setting.1, setting.2 = setting.2)
```

Based on these I would like to do simulations using each cohort (each line in the *cohorts* data frame).
I've been trying using `replicate`

```
sim_list = replicate(n = nrow(cohorts),
            expr = {data.frame(
                            time.1 = rexp(n, ir.1),
                            time.2 = rexp(n, ir.2)
                            )}, simplify = F            
            )

str(sim_list)                                                                                    
List of 48
 $ :'data.frame':       10000 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ time.1: num [1:10000] 156.75 68.2 4.81 105.74 29.82 ...
  ..$ time.2: num [1:10000] 5.66 13.08 3.88 3.32 23.99 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       10000 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ time.1: num [1:10000] 134.7 48.1 30.9 46 104.2 ...
  ..$ time.2: num [1:10000] 20.57 2.38 1.64 2.49 1.53 ...
................
```

From this I do get a list of 48 dataframes with 10000 rows each, but the exponential function draws seem to be based on the same setting each time.

I want sim_list[[1]]'s draws to be based the setting in first line of **cohorts** (cohorts[1,]), sim_list[[2]]'s draws to be based on cohorts[2,] and so on...

This would result in the mean of each dataframe's time.1 values to range from approx. 20 - 100 (based on ir.1's values), but they do range from approx. 55-58 *(equivalent to a rexp draw using the mean of the 3 values in ir.1???)* :

```
range(lapply(sim_list, function(x) { mean(x[['time.1']])}))
[1] 55.49693 58.35876
```

The problem is probably using the `replicate` function for this, but I can't figure out how to do it otherwise. Create one big dataframe and group them by the cohort number? Using some kind of apply function? Anything else?

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to simulate some data for each combination of parameters. Two issues with your code, 1) replicate does not do what you might think, 2) the reason why the results are the same is because it uses the same variable which you defined at the start, not the values in your data frame.

Here is an alternative

```
sim_list = function(cohorts) {
  data.frame(
    time.1 = rexp(cohorts["n"], cohorts["ir.1"]),
    time.2 = rexp(cohorts["n"], cohorts["ir.2"])
  )
}

res=apply(cohorts,1,sim_list)
```

To check ranges of time.1

```
lapply(lapply(res,"[[",1),range)
```